# Eclipse C/C++ not finding compiler include directories - cannot even build hello world

Tags: c++, eclipse

Do I need to install Eclipse as an administrator to get it to run correctly? I currently am in my user account on my work laptop. Eclipse C/C++ is not properly configuring itself when I start it: doesn't know where the MinGW and MSYS files are. (And yes, I included the links to the binaries in the system path).

Comment: Didn't you have to configure the compiler settings on a project or environment manually?

Comment: @VermillionAzure yea, I found out where to get Eclipse to automatically include the MinGW include paths

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work, here's what I did:

1. Opened MinGW setup **as administrator**
2. Set permissions for C:\MinGW to read and write for all users (didn't have this before).
3. Used 7-Zip to extract Eclipse to C:\eclipse
4. Also gave that folder full read-write privileged
5. Upon startup, I enabled auto discovery in the new project makefile settings. See pic below:

[image]